# Is FIFO in a queue is equivalent to LILO?

Tags: data-structures, stack, queue, fifo, lifo

I am a little confused here.

The [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/queue-data-structure/) said:

> A Queue is a linear structure which follows a particular order in which the operations are performed. The order is First In First Out (FIFO). A good example of a queue is any queue of consumers for a resource where the consumer that came first is served first. The difference between stacks and queues is in removing. In a stack we remove the item the most recently added; in a queue, we remove the item the least recently added.

Is it right to say that FIFO (first in, first out) is the same as LILO (last in, last out)?

And for stacks: is it the same as LIFO (last in, first out) and FILO (first in, last out)?

But no one ever uses LILO and FILO.

Comment: because it is standardized around a wording for better recognition and quicker relaying of information. You are a human, yet if i referred to you as a homo sapiens it is the same thing we are talking about.

Comment: Thanks. 
So it is totally the same, am I right?

Comment: Yeah, if i told you "you are the last one in the line and so you will be last person to go on the rollercoaster". It is the same as "the person first in line will go to the rollercoaster first, and so on till the last person"

Comment: Ok. Can you make the answer, so I will be able to close this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in the cases of both stacks and queues, either naming convention is technically accurate.

Consider a queue of size 4. We enqueue "o", then enqueue "x", and they're put in the queue in that respective order.

```
     +---+---+---+---+
Back |   |   | x | o | Front
     +---+---+---+---+
```

When we dequeue, the element closest to the front is removed from the queue, and the rest of the queue "moves up" to look like:

```
     +---+---+---+---+
Back |   |   |   | x | Front (o dequeued)
     +---+---+---+---+
```

In this abstract example, "o" is the first element to be enqueued (first in), and the first element to be dequeued (first out).

Then, we can dequeue again, and receive x.

```
     +---+---+---+---+
Back |   |   |   |   | Front (x dequeued)
     +---+---+---+---+
```

Now, it is easy to see from this dequeue that "x" is the last element to be enqueued (last in), and the last element to be dequeued (last out).

Therefore, FIFO and LILO are equivalent terminology.

For brevity, I'll condense the example for a stack:

```
+---+    +---+    +---+
|   |    |   |    |   |
+---+    +---+    +---+
|   |    |   |    |   |
+---+    +---+    +---+
|   |    | x |    |   |
+---+    +---+    +---+
| o |    | o |    | o |
+---+    +---+    +---+
Push o   Push x   Pop
```

In the second step, "x" becomes the last element pushed to the stack (last in). Then, when we pop, the top element of the stack gets removed, which is still "x" (last out).

If we were to pop a second time, we could be given "o". This element was the first in, and the last element to be removed. Therefore, the behavior can be described by both LIFO and FILO.

As for why one naming convention is used over the other, -*("/)*-

Answer (score 3):

As stated before, LILO and FIFO are essentially the same, except for the status of the structure/memory. With FIFO (First In First Out), the first element pushed in will be the first element popped off (if the stack is empty at the beginning).
If the queue is not empty and we push an element "A", for the agent the "first in" element is "A", but we will pop the ***first element* stored in the queue**, which could be any element stored earlier! The "first in" element will be popped out as "first out" element only if the queue is empty.
A LILO queue does not care about the status of the queue: the last pushed element will be the last popped element whatever the number of elements pushed before or stored in the queue.
*So, strictly speaking a FIFO structure also tells us more information about the stack: it is empty by default; a LILO structure behaves in the same way but does not care about the transient (queue state).* Same logic for FILO and LIFO.

Comment: This seems like a valuable answer but the first 3 or 4 sentences need editing to make it clearer what you mean -- can you edit?